# CQL:Given column is not of UDT type

Tags: cassandra, cql, cql3

I have this table

```
create table constants_values
              (
               key_name_1 text,
               key_name_2 text,
               values map<text, frozen<nav_tag_values>>,
               PRIMARY KEY(key_name_1, key_name_2)
              );
```

UDT:

```
 CREATE TYPE ks_mobApp.nav_tag_values (
               values set<text>
              );
```

Here i am inserting values:

`INSERT INTO constants_values(key_name_1,key_name_2,values) 
VALUES('Sell', 'Electronics', {'Mobile': {value : {'Laptop'}});`

No in java if I do

`row.getUDTValue("values")` it says `values` is not UDT type

What i am missing ?

Answer (score 1):

You should do:

```
Map<String,UDTValue> myMap = row.getMap("values", String.class, UDTValue.class);

UDTValue myUdt = myMap.get("Mobile");
```